# Wrong data type in in_array function in kohana framework?

Tags: php, kohana

I have two controllers, one is base controller, other is `subject` in the base controller I defined some arrays from Model, look:

```
class Controller_Base extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'main';

    public function before()
    {
        parent::before();

        $webs = array();
        $apps = array();

        $app = new Model_Application();
        $apps = $app->get_all();

        $web = new Model_Web();
        $webs = $web->get_all();

        $this->template->content = '';
        $this->template->styles = array('style');
        $this->template->scripts = '';

        $this->template->webs = $webs;
        $this->template->apps = $apps;

    }

}
```

in the controller subject I am using function in_array

```
class Controller_Subject extends Controller_Base {

public function action_all()
{

    $url = $this->request->param('url');

    $this->template->caption = $url;


    if (in_array($url,$this->template->webs)) { 
        echo "web";
    }
        elseif (in_array($url,$this->template->apps)) { 
        echo "apps";
    }

    $links = array("a"=>"1","b"=>"2");

    $view = View::factory('subject')
                ->set('links',$links);

    $this->template->content = $view;

}

}
```

but the Kohana returns me an error:

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: in_array() [<a href='function.in-array'>function.in-array</a>]: Wrong datatype for second argument
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: You can do `var_dump($webs)` and see what's data in that variable. My guess there is an object, not array.

Comment: yes, there is an object: ``object(Database_MySQL_Result)#24 (7) { ["_internal_row:protected"]=> int(0) ["_query:protected"]=> string(18) "SELECT * FROM webs" ["_result:protected"]=> resource(73) of type (mysql result) ["_total_rows:protected"]=> int(5) ["_current_row:protected"]=> int(0) ["_as_object:protected"]=> bool(false) ["_object_params:protected"]=> NULL }``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need array variables instead of Database_Result objects:

```
...
$apps = $app->get_all()->as_array();
...
$webs = $web->get_all()->as_array();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The Models returned data, that is, `Database_MySQL_Result`, needs to be changed to an array first.
you can use

```
foreach($query as $v) 
    $arr[]=$v; 
return $arr;
```

in your `get_all()`.